# How to Prevent Browser HTTP Authentication Dialog from Appearing w/Devise and jQuery Mobile

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to use Devise authentication and jQuery Mobile for a Rails 3 project. I've added the data-role stuff to my devise views and I can do things like register a new user without any problems. In fact, I can sign in without any problems as long as I correctly type the email and password. If I type something wrong the browser throws up an HTTP authentication dialog box. My config\initializers\devise.rb file already contains:

```
Devise.setup do |config|  
    config.http_authenticatable = false  
    config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = false  
    config.navigational_formats = [:html, :js]  
end
```

I know this has something to do with jQuery Mobile using AJAX to submit the form and returning a 401 response, but I have no idea what I need to do to make it behave like a normal page where it just re-renders it with the flash message.

I'm totally new to AJAX and jQuery so the more details in an answer the better.

Thanks!

Comment: try not using AJAX for that submit. That's the only simple way. You would have to alter your solution for logging in to make it work with AJAX [and I bet you don't want to]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think I finally figured this out. I had the a1 versions of jQuery Mobile CSS and JS files in my application.mobile.erb file AND I needed to shut down my browser on my iPhone to clear the cache. Anyway, I think that is what resolved the problem. It seems to be working fine now.